# AVAudioPlayer doesn't work with phone speaker?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play sounds when a button is tap. The sounds only play with earpiece plug in, it does not work with phone speaker. I have try to turn the volume to loudest, but still the same. I know in android there is different category for sounds but is it the same for iOS? The following is my code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

@IBAction func Lock(sender: UIButton) {
    let soundURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mission_completed", withExtension: "mp3")!
    audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.volume = 1
    audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: answer to my own question, i can get the thing work just to add var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

Comment: i have tested this and it works in any case. do you use elsewhere audioplayer in your app ?